# Freshly installed Ubuntu freezes up after a few minutes

Tags: performance

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 like 70 minutes ago, but I'm having a problem I've never had before; after some minutes of use, the system simply freezes; nothing works at all.

I've tested and only USB devices still function for some time After 1 minute I guess it simply stops, just showing me vvio and with normal HDD noises audible inside the case.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you run 18.04 from a live media drive (ie not installed)? Does it also lock up or only after install. When locked can you switch to a terminal Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in - if you can, does `dmesg` give any error information (you can view similar info with `less /var/log/messages*` too - type `:n` to move to next file).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think  I've found the error; the Firefox package was corrupted. I've uninstalled it completely and reinstalled it, and now it appears that the system is working fine.